# How do you create a non-nested xml element using Python's lxml.objectify?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

My current code is

```
xml_obj = lxml.objectify.Element('root_name')
xml_obj[root_name] = str('text')
lxml.etree.tostring(xml_obj)
```

but this creates the following xml:

```
<root_name><root_name>text</root_name></root_name>
```

In the application I am using this for I could easily use text substitution to solve this problem, but it would be nice to know how to do it using the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with `objectify`, but i don't think that's the way it's intended to be used. The way it represents objects, is that a node at any given level is, say, a classname, and the subnodes are field names (with types) and values. And the normal way to use it would be something more like this:

```
xml_obj = lxml.objectify.Element('xml_obj')
xml_obj.root_path = 'text'
etree.dump(xml_obj)
<root_name xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" py:pytype="TREE">
  <root_name py:pytype="str">text</root_name>
</root_name>
```

What you want would be way easier to do with `etree`:

```
xml_obj = lxml.etree.Element('root_path')
xml_obj.text = 'text'
etree.dump(xml_obj)
<root_path>text</root_path>
```

If you really need it to be in `objectify`, it looks like while you shouldn't mix directly, you can use `tostring` to generate XML, then `objectify.fromstring` to bring it back. But probably, if this is what you want, you should just use `etree` to generate it.

Comment: Thanks! I had been using Objectify because I was familiar with it, but you are completely right about etree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write data into the root element. You may need to create a child element like this:

```
xml_obj = lxml.objectify.Element('root_name')
xml_obj.child_name = str('text')
lxml.etree.tostring(xml_obj)
```